# Read a .jpg from RAM

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import requests

response = requests.get(image.url)

# Works fine, but requests a disk write.
f = open('tmp.jpg', 'bw')
f.write(response.content)
img = Image.open('tmp.jpg')

# Fails with `OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.StringIO object at 0x7fb666238a68>`
#file = StringIO(str(response.content))
#img = Image.open(file)
```

I am trying to run the code from [this tutorial](http://visualgenome.org/api/v0/api_beginners_tutorial.html) but in python3. The commented out version is the closest I have gone to the original idea of "get an image from the network into RAM and work with that". I don't mind using `cv2` if easier. How do I write this code pythonically and efficiently?

Comment: I can't tell what you actually want to do, but you can either use `cv2.imdecode()` to convert an in-memory JPEG/PNG into a Numpy array that OpenCV can process, or you can wrap it in an `io.BytesIO()` and use PIL `Image.open()` with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Setchell said, you likely want `BytesIO` not `StringIO`.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import requests

response = requests.get(image.url)

file = BytesIO(response.content)
img = Image.open(file)
```